# comparing two object attributes Return 500

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm doing a validation check and see if both objects in `items` have the same `paymentProcessor`, if not I need to throw an Error. So I created a new list and added these attributes to the list, then I did the following

```
if(!(Collections.frequency(paymentProcessor, paymentProcessor.get(0)) == paymentProcessor.size())){
    throw new ExceptionHandler("Multiple payment processor is not supported!");
}
```

the Problem is whenever the `ExceptionHandler` triggers it gives me 500 internal server error instead of displaying the error message.

//this is my Json

```
"items": [
        {
            "paymentProcessor": "MPGS",
            "type": "CARD",
        },
        {
            "paymentProcessor": "xx",
            "type": "CARD",
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle the exception somewhere.
See https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring for some examples.

If it is a REST service, you should use the @RestControllerAdvice annotation.
Have a look at https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-restcontrolleradvice/ for a tutorial.

In short: This component is catching at the end the exception, and you can decide there how you want to answer.

In the best case, you'll have your own exception(s), which can get the message and for example the HTTP status code as a constructor argument.

Then you can throw this exception and catch it in this `ControllerAdvice`. There you can prepare the response and send it back.

This can look like this:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalRestExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessageDto> handleMyCustomExceptionException(
            final MyCustomException exception) {
        final var errorMessage = new ErrorMessageDto();
        errorMessage.setMessage(exception.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.status(exception.getStatus()).body(errorMessage);
    }
}
```